# Change Preference Item Summary Text Color in Android 4

Tags: android, colors, themes, preference

I have the below sample of preference items

```
 <CheckBoxPreference
     android:key="chkSound"
     android:summary="Sound is Off"
     android:title="Sound" />
```

I use a theme in the res/values to change the Summary text color

```
 <style name="ThemeDarkText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
  </style>
```

And in the code I write this line

```
    setTheme(R.style.ThemeDarkText);
```

Its working fine in Android 2.1 but when I tried to run it on a different os (ex Android 4.0)
It didn't change the summary text color just the title color only..!!

Any help?

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem here.

What was interesting was that the summary of Edit Preference was colored properly - red, but the Checkbox and the PreferenceScreen were white.

This is my solution:

Add this to the style.xml in your theme:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: this is working but for some reason is changing the drawer menu item icons, it makes to them some kind of some colour overlay . Any idea?

Comment: This also changes the three dots color on the toolbar, I don't want that. Any ideas?

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 That means dots using that color category from the theme. Google's fault. The better way - make your own widget class and don't mess with google at all.

Answer (score 1):

For those using `Theme.AppCompat` (Lollipop), this is controlled by

`<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>`